# ikev2provider blocking connections - misconfigured vpn settings - stuck on the same IP

Tags: network, wifi, keychain, vpn, catalina

I am currently struggling with very weird macOS problems. I am running Catalina on a macbook pro 2018. For the past few days I have experienced connection issues:

- The first problem was when I returned to work after vacation and could not connect to any of our internal services.
- A quick check showed that I was getting an external IP from Denmark. Alright that is unexpected. Then I used some ip checker tools to get some more informations, and I saw that the IP was one of NordVPNs servers.
- Alright - so I don't seem to have a malware proxy (what I first thought) but rather a misconfigured VPN connection. The VPN client app was not active at this point and every manual vpn connection in the network app was inactive or disabled.
- So now I knew the problem seems to be NordVPN, so I deleted the app, deleted every network adapter vpn setting, deleted all places where I could find nordvpn files

Places where I deleted nordVPN related stuff:

```
- ~/Library/Application\ Support/  
- ~/Library/Caches
- ~/Library/Logs
- ~/Library/Preferences
- ~/Library/Containers
```

I also tried restarting the mDNSResponder several times with `sudo killall mDNSresponder` and I tried deleting the network configs in `~/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration`:

```
com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
com.apple.network.identification.plist
NetworkInterfaces.plist
preferences.plist
```

- Afterwards I restarted the machine and it seemed to work, but only for some time (minutes to hours) before my IP changes again and a VPN connection is active.
- So it seems like somewhere in the system there are still credentials/certificates stored. So I opened the mac keychain and deleted every nordVPN credential and root certificates. Another restart later the problem has changed a little bit:

Now I could not get ANY connection (I could use `ping` and would get the expected output but could not use curl or any browser). So somehow the approach with deleting all credentials seemed to have some effect.

- For the next step I wanted to find out which process was starting up the VPN connection. So I consulted the `system.log` and the macOS console. I've seen many many entries from the `IKEv2Provider` service (the mac vpn service process) with a status like `"Tunnel:NordVPN:"some hex code here"` with the Description: `"Received a start command from "programXY[pid]""` Unfortunately I don't have the exact wording as I restored the complete machine in the meantime to factory settings and did not save the logs. There was another logfile where it also mentioned the `IKEv2Provider` process quite often with something like: `process remained dirty for too long. Killing` which showed up many times too.

So the problem seems to be this process, but it seems to get the start command from random apps, I was seeing processes like calendar.agent, spotify, firefox etc. starting it up.

- So that was the last step before I said screw it and restored the machine to factory settings. Another problem is that the issue persists when I restore from my timemachine backup, either I need to find an older backup which is not compromised or I need to restore only files and apps but not system settings? I will try that out later today.

I've already somehow settled with a factory reset and a partial-recovery of my important things like dotfiles, IDE settings and stuff, but my system settings will be lost, so some kind of solution would be preferred.

I can always go back to the "corrupted" backup, so if anyone here has a idea what else to do or has every heard of something similar I would love to hear your tips, and if it's promising I can restore the machine to the faulty state and try out some more things.

Additional Info:

- At some point deleting and re-adding all wifi connections seemed to work, but only for some time until the VPN kicked in again.
- I have contacted NordVPNs support, but so far I only received the usual tips, maybe they will escalate the ticket to a dev.
- When I had the NordVPN client still installed and clicked on Quick Connect it connected to the server I was already on! So my IP did not change at all but the Client reported that it is connected. Connecting to different countries still worked, I would get a UK-IP when I connected to the UK, but when I disconnected I still was on the NordVPN IP from Denmark. What I would expect from Quick Connect (And experienced in the past) is that it connects to a German or Switzerland server (I am located in southern Germany) but never to a server in Denmark.
- All of this stuff happened after I was vacationing in the Netherlands. I heavily used my VPN there (Lots of open wifis) and it feels like that is part of the reason it won't disappear afterwards. (When located in the Netherlands getting a quick-connect server in Denmark would make a little bit more sense)
- What bugs me out the most is that the logs showed `Tunnel:NordVPN` AFTER I deleted every file/keychain entry/certificate mentioning NordVPN, so there has to be some kind of hidden entry somewhere which I can't find.

I am sorry for the long text, but I tried collecting all the steps I already tried out, I think it is not an common problem but I hope that we somehow find a solution, I would love to avoid restoring only part of my files, and use my complete backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem myself:

The culprit was `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.networkextension.plist` - there were entries for the IP I was always conecting too, my vpn login email and strings like "nordvpn.osx". (Not to be confused with the path `~/Library/Preferences`!) I deleted everything related to vpn and after a restart it worked again. I needed to download XCode to edit the `.plist`, and you have to copy it to a directory with r+w permission, and copy it back to the protected `Preferences` directory after editing.